# Monitor and computer not working together

Tags: graphics-card, display

I have a LCD monitor (Connected via VGA, 15", max res 1024x768, so far from good). This monitor will not work with a specific computer (Windows XP SP3, integrated Intel graphics card of some description) when the computer is booted up. It will show the BIOS screen, then a black screen with white dots that steadily fill the screen until it displays an out of range error.

Any other monitor I have works on that PC.

Any other PC I have works with that monitor.

Furthermore, if I boot up the system with another monitor, then plug out the other monitor and insert the problem monitor while the system is in use, the problem monitor works fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start your computer by pressing F8, use VGA mode.
2. Then change your display setting to correct setting.

Comment: How do I find the correct setting? I don't know the specs on the monitor.

Comment: trial and error

Comment: If your monitor supports plug & play, then when you change your display setting you will only be able to choose only supported values. Even if you choose some settings that are not supported you just wait until resolution goes back. (Since when you change the display setting you have to confirm the settings). **(You may break your display if it's too old (model) and you choose a too hight refresh rate)**

Comment: Use the setting of the "another monitor" from your post.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh rate seems to be the problem.  If you correct it everything should be fine.

Comment: How can I correct it?

Comment: It's in display properties advanced